# Is there a data type in MsSQL bigger than float?

Tags: sql-server

I am currently working with some ErlangC calculations to determine occupancy rates. I've got the functions I need working but when I start getting into higher numbers such as POWER(145,145), ~2.50242070x10^313, I get the following:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type float.

Is there anything in MsSQL I can use to handle these larger numbers? MS Excel can, but MsSQL can't?

Comment: AFAIK, your only native options are VARCHAR (convert your number to a String) and VARBINARY (convert your number to a byte array), and obviously you won't be able to use most SQL Server math functions on those.  On the plus side, they're 100% accurate!

Comment: There isn't a datatype in sql server that can hold that many significant digits. What about maybe some division on the expression first. Something like POWER(1.45, 145) instead? You might get some rounding errors but those are huge numbers.

Comment: Curious to know what building has potential occupancy in the region of 10^313...

Comment: The decimal datatype I think can hold bigger numbers.

Comment: @ChrisPickford maybe it's calculating the occupancy of how many air molecules can fit inside...

Comment: @TabAlleman No, the DECIMAL data type is a precise floating point number value limited to 38 decimal places.  10^313 has, well, 313 decimal places.  POWER(145,145) is [larger than a 1024-bit number](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(log+(145%5E145))+%2F+(log(2))).

Comment: Oh I just meant it can hold bigger numbers than FLOAT.   I think.   It can definitely hold bigger number than INT.

Comment: @TabAlleman DECIMAL and NUMERIC have more precision (38 decimal places) but much less range.  They're +/-10^38 and +/-10^-38, but the precision is limited to the same 38 decimal places for the whole field, so you can't have both 10^-20 and 10^20 in the same NUMERIC column.  FLOAT has a range of roughly +/-10^308 and +/-10^-308 *and* can represent all those values in the same column, but never actually stores more than 17 decimal places, and is only going to be accurate to the first 8 to 10 places typically.

Comment: Thinking about it some more, you *may* be able to use [BigRational](http://bcl.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BigRational&referringTitle=Home) as a [CLR User-Defined Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131120.aspx), but that's far beyond what I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really hard. Not even Excel can handle this number. Excel can handle until 145^142 = 8.2084E+306. If you try 145^143 you will get an error.
CLR data types also do not handle this number, so CLR Data Type is not an option.

As ErlangC calculations are done for traffic modeling, I would review your process to see if you are using the correct units on your formula (minutes, seconds, etc). This number is really really big to be achieved in a Call Center if this is your case.

Comment: ErlangC based on half-hour intervals uses the following: Intensity = (CallVolume / 1800) * AverageCallDuration(in seconds). This is then applied to the following: (Intensity^(FLOOR(Intensity))) / FACTORIAL(FLOOR(Intensity)). In a customer service call center with an expected call volume of 800 calls per half hour with an average call duration of 6 minutes (360 seconds) results in an Intensity of 159.999840. POWER(159.999840,159) is too much.